# Setting up Wordpress on a NearlyFreeSpeech hosted server

Tags: mysql, wordpress, nearlyfreespeech

I'm tearing my hair out with this issue I'm having. I'm doing an install of Wordpress onto my [NearlyFreeSpeech](http://nearlyfreespeech.net) web server. I've already set up my MySQL database and such, and it's working just fine. I've set up a user called `wpuser` and a database called `wpuser` as well, and given `wpuser` the proper permissions to create/drop and such.

I've edited my `wp-config.php` exactly how the NearlyFreeSpeech FAQ lists.

Upon hitting the install button I get errors like this:

```
WordPress database error: [Can't create/write to file '/var/wordpress/wp_users.MYI' (Errcode: 2)]`
```

And then the long MySQL query follows. I don't have permissions to access anything other than my public/private folders on the server, so I don't know why Wordpress is trying to seemingly install itself into the var folder, or at least access a folder that's not there.

A little bit of searching suggested that I give Wordpress a temporary directory, which I have done using this code:

```
if ( !defined('WP_TEMP_DIR') )
    define('WP_TEMP_DIR', dirname(__FILE__) . '/tmp/');
```

Any suggestions on how I can get this thing to actually install?

---

My `wp-config.php`:

```
<?php
/**
 * The base configurations of the WordPress.
 *
 * This file has the following configurations: MySQL settings, Table Prefix,
 * Secret Keys, WordPress Language, and ABSPATH. You can find more information
 * by visiting {@link http://codex.wordpress.org/Editing_wp-config.php Editing
 * wp-config.php} Codex page. You can get the MySQL settings from your web host.
 *
 * This file is used by the wp-config.php creation script during the
 * installation. You don't have to use the web site, you can just copy this file
 * to "wp-config.php" and fill in the values.
 *
 * @package WordPress
 */

// ** MySQL settings - You can get this info from your web host ** //
/** The name of the database for WordPress */
define('DB_NAME', 'wpuser');

/** MySQL database username */
define('DB_USER', 'wpuser');

/** MySQL database password */
define('DB_PASSWORD', "passwordhere");

/** MySQL hostname */
define('DB_HOST', 'nescience.db');

/** Database Charset to use in creating database tables. */
define('DB_CHARSET', 'utf8');

/** The Database Collate type. Don't change this if in doubt. */
define('DB_COLLATE', '');



if ( !defined('WP_TEMP_DIR') )
    define('WP_TEMP_DIR', dirname(__FILE__) . '/tmp/');





/**#@+
 * Authentication Unique Keys and Salts.
 *
 * Change these to different unique phrases!
 * You can generate these using the {@link https://api.wordpress.org/secret-key/1.1/salt/ WordPress.org secret-key service}
 * You can change these at any point in time to invalidate all existing cookies. This will force all users to have to log in again.
 *
 * @since 2.6.0
 */
define('AUTH_KEY',         'put your unique phrase here');
define('SECURE_AUTH_KEY',  'put your unique phrase here');
define('LOGGED_IN_KEY',    'put your unique phrase here');
define('NONCE_KEY',        'put your unique phrase here');
define('AUTH_SALT',        'put your unique phrase here');
define('SECURE_AUTH_SALT', 'put your unique phrase here');
define('LOGGED_IN_SALT',   'put your unique phrase here');
define('NONCE_SALT',       'put your unique phrase here');

/**#@-*/

/**
 * WordPress Database Table prefix.
 *
 * You can have multiple installations in one database if you give each a unique
 * prefix. Only numbers, letters, and underscores please!
 */
$table_prefix  = 'wp_';

/**
 * WordPress Localized Language, defaults to English.
 *
 * Change this to localize WordPress. A corresponding MO file for the chosen
 * language must be installed to wp-content/languages. For example, install
 * de_DE.mo to wp-content/languages and set WPLANG to 'de_DE' to enable German
 * language support.
 */
define('WPLANG', '');

/**
 * For developers: WordPress debugging mode.
 *
 * Change this to true to enable the display of notices during development.
 * It is strongly recommended that plugin and theme developers use WP_DEBUG
 * in their development environments.
 */
define('WP_DEBUG', false);

/* That's all, stop editing! Happy blogging. */

/** Absolute path to the WordPress directory. */
if ( !defined('ABSPATH') )
    define('ABSPATH', dirname(__FILE__) . '/');

/** Sets up WordPress vars and included files. */
require_once(ABSPATH . 'wp-settings.php');
```

Comment: Are you using the right database server?  It's probably not `localhost`, though I don't know the specifics of NearlyFreeSpeech's setup.

Comment: Errcode 2 means file not found, I believe. Are you sure you have specified the right host server?

Comment: My database host is `<databasename>.db` as suggested by their FAQ. If I use a different one with garbage letters the page won't even load, it just gives me `error establishing a database connection`. So, regrettably I don't think that's the issue.

If `errcode 2` is file not found, why is it trying to look for a wordpress directory under `/var`?

Comment: This sounds like something is wrong with the database config. Most likely an issue for the server admins.

Comment: @Pekka웃 Yeah, that's what I was worried about. The nature of the issue seems server related, but their support is not free. I tried to submit a server error ticket for an issue that was server related but they closed it on the grounds that it was my fault and I had to pay to get support for the problem.

Comment: I just tried deleting the MySQL process through NFS and recreating it. No luck.

Answer (score 1):

I know this is old but I thought it would be helpful to answer.
I followed this advice, and it worked fine:

https://members.nearlyfreespeech.net/YOURMEMBERNAME/support/wordpress

Also see this:

http://www.reddit.com/r/Wordpress/comments/18e5n9/anyone_use_nearlyfreespeech_as_a_webdev_babynoob/

Summary:

```
touch .htaccess
chgrp web .htaccess
chmod 664 .htaccess
chgrp -R web *
find . -type d -exec chmod 775 {} \;
find . -type f -exec chmod 664 {} \;
```

Your wp-config.php file looks fine. Your database name looks correct.

Did you use wp-cli to download wordpress?  That's what I did and it worked well.

```
curl -O https://raw.githubusercontent.com/wp-cli/builds/gh-pages/phar/wp-cli.phar    
php wp-cli.phar core download
```

And then i invoked this:

http://MYSITENAME.nfshost.com/wp-admin/install.php

and it all worked.

Comment: I'm definitely past the point of needing this information but I really appreciate you posting this - this looks like this should be the solution.

Answer (score 0):

<strike>nescience.db is not the address of the database server. It doesn't resolve.The URL of your database is located at the top of PHP My Admin.</strike>

---

**Edit:**

Some hosting companies install the MySql on the same instance as Apache. Its worth a shot to try **localhost**.

```
/** MySQL hostname */
define( 'DB_HOST', 'localhost' );
```

---

**EDIT**

Correction: nescience.db is probably the right name for the MySQL Server. On NearlyFreeSpeech, this is how they name their databases.

Comment: In the context of my hosting provider, it is.

http://i.imgur.com/lKbXhH3.png

Despite it not being a conventional hostname, it's what NFS requires. I changed the database name in the meantime, that's why it's a different name, by the way.

Comment: No luck. Whenever I change the hostname to something other than `nescienceband.db` I can't even get to the install page, it just gives me an error and doesn't load the page. I'm pretty confident that the hostname is correct. I appreciate the help.

Comment: What if you set group owner to and owner to apache?

Comment: NFS also mentions in their FAQ that you should set the files (or at least the uses files and directories) to the `web` group. I've done so, but I can give `apache` a try.

Comment: To be honest what your trying to do should not be this hard. AWS offers a free micro instance for the first year, check it out.

Answer (score 0):

This is really about the names used for database things in WordPress and NFS.

in phpMyAdmin on your site... at the top of the page look for...
Server: name1.db »Database: name2

define('DB_NAME', name2');
define('DB_HOST', 'name1.db');
The username and password are for the user you made for this MYSQL site.
Hope this helps